# What could be hiding a button in XAML grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a button that works in other places within the page.  If I add it to a particular grid though, it gets displayed but it's not clickable.  Here's my full markup for that:

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource NogMasterPageGridStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Page title -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        // THIS BUTTON SHOULD BE CLICKABLE, AND IS ELSEWHERE
        <Button IsHitTestVisible="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Canvas.ZIndex="9999" Content="Go Back" Style="{StaticResource NogButton}" 
                            Click="Click_GoBack"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="40,0,0,0">
            <Image Style="{StaticResource NogLogoImage}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="NOG"  Style="{StaticResource NogPageTitle}"  
                    IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="2,-35,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

What could be causing the button to not be clickable in this particular grid?

Edit:  I tried disabling the style of the grid and that didn't work.  Here it is just in case:

```
<Style x:Key="NogButton"
       TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ColorBrushWhite}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ColorBrushGreen}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
</Style>
<ImageBrush x:Key="BackgroundNog" 
            ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/WhiteBackgroundAndPen.jpg" 
            Stretch="UniformToFill" />

<Style x:Key="NogMasterPageGridStyle"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}"
       TargetType="Panel">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundNog}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Your GridStyle could be the culprit, post the Style also

Comment: As Sajeetharan mentioned it is something related to the styles. Are you able to supply the NogMasterPageGridStyle and NogButton styles?

Comment: @RobVious Your xaml and button click works without any problem

Comment: @RobVious I am not able to reproduce your problem. I am able to click on the button.

Comment: Thanks for trying this out @Jamleck.  No idea what's breaking it, even with no styles on the grid or button, I can't click any buttons I put in that top grid.

Comment: @RobVious Is your mouse working ? :P

Comment: @Sajeetharan I swear it is!  I even put the same exact button somewhere else on the page and it works perfectly.  So frustrating

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to solve this issue by using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), it is a wonderful application that lets you view all the layers of you wpf app, and also view the data contexts and you can change the properties values. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you set IsHitTestVisible to False on some ancestor in the parent chain of the Button? That could be the reason.

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> ... if an element is a child element of an element that is not hit test visible, the effective value of the property on the child will remain false, even if attempting to set that value locally.